# How important are GPUs vs. CPUs when training an LLM?

Tags: gpu, llm

I want to train my very own large language model. I have some data, and access to an open-source foundational model. Can I use my laptop that only has a CPU and no GPU to train the model? Do I need to rent time on a cloud provider to get a VM with GPUs?

Comment: This question would be substantially improved by describing the type of LLM you had in mind. As it is written now then answer is a really long “it depends.”

Answer (score 4):

Tl;dr you *can* (usually) do it CPU-only, but it will take a very long time.

Note: I mention a number of products in this answer. While I have used some of them, I'm not affiliated with them, nor am I suggesting/endorsing any specific product here. Do your research to ensure anything you purchase suits your requirements.

It depends on your specific model and the GPU, but *generally* training models on one (or more!) GPUs vastly improves training speed. Technically speaking, it isn't required (in some cases). But it's highly preferable given the option.

If you're training an extremely small model, it *might* be faster on a CPU. Or if you're comparing a Dell PowerEdge server with multiple Xeons to a very old cheap GPU.

Assuming you're trying to train a decent-sized generative model, though, having a GPU is *extremely* useful. Some models require a specific brand of GPU, such as if you're going to use [NVIDIA CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) or similar, so know your requirements prior to making purchases. There's a few ways to get a GPU if you only have a laptop.

Some laptops* have a [Thunderbolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)) port that you can use to connect to an [eGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit#External_GPU_(eGPU)). This is typically done with an eGPU enclosure ([here](https://www.razer.com/gaming-egpus/razer-core-x)'s one, as an example). It's also possible to not have an actual enclosure, though. In some cases, you can also use an onboard M.2 connector. Also note that the existence of a USB-C port does *not* mean you automatically have Thunderbolt. Actually check your laptop specs. Specifics of that, though, are beyond the scope of this question.

As mentioned, some cloud providers will let you rent a VPS with a GPU. While an option, the price can be cost-prohibitive. It can make sense in some situations, though.

Another option, similar to a VPS, is something like [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com). It's essentially a Python notebook in a browser with free access to GPUs. With this option, note that there are limitations on how much you can use it and for what purpose.

---

*And some desktops, but mostly laptops

Answer (score -3):

> Can I use my laptop that only has CPUs and no GPU to train the model.

No. You need GPUs if you don't want to wait for a few years or more. How many and which GPUs will depend on the model, the training data and your patience.